# Variable Timesteps and Gravity/Friction

Tags: game-physics, lwjgl, slick2d, 2d-games

I'm trying to copy the logic of the [Sonic physics engine](http://info.sonicretro.org/SPG%3aJumping), which was written for a fixed-timestep system (60 FPS), in a variable timestep age (Slick2D, to be precise).

In the original upon pressing the jump button, the player's `velocity.y` is set to -6.5, and each tick 0.21875 is added to `velocity.y` to model gravity.

Each time my logic update is called, a time delta parameter is passed specifying how many millis have passed. If more millis have passed than I was expecting, then I repeat the update logic, passing an 'inner delta' that is at most 1, or less if we're dealing with the 'remainder' of a target frame.

E.g. if we expect a frame to take 16ms, and it *does* take 16 ms, the loop will iterate once and pass `thisMiniTick` as 1. If the delta was not 16ms but 40ms, the loop will execute three times, passing 1, 1, and finally 0.5.

I mistakenly thought that in each of these inner update loops I could do `velocity.y += (gravity * thisMiniTickRelative)`, but this doesn't work. On faster framerates not enough gravity is applied causing a higher jump, and on slower framerates the jump is lower (although not anywhere near as noticeably).

Is there a way of doing this that will work for virtually all framerates, or must I resort to setting an upper and lower bound for `delta`?

The 'inner update' loop:

```
    float timeRemaining = delta/1000f; 
    while(timeRemaining > 0)
    {
        float thisMiniTick = Math.min(timeRemaining, 1f / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
        float thisMiniTickRelative = thisMiniTick / (1f / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);

        updateInput(container, game, thisMiniTickRelative);
        if (playerAirState)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += (GRAVITY * thisMiniTickRelative);
        }
        clampPlayerVelocity();
        playerPosition.add(playerVelocity);
        doCollisions();
        timeRemaining -= thisMiniTick;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of it as "resorting to setting an upper and lower bound for `delta`". Your application and threads are subject to the OS scheduling time for your app, among all the other demands on the system, and something you just need to be aware of. This challenge is as old in PC gaming as the day we moved from single-tasking operating systems to multi-tasking operating systems.

With Slick, you can (and should) disconnect your logic updates from your rendering updates, which is why the `delta` value gets passed around your application. Do this by using the [.setMinimumLogicUpdateInterval and .setMaximumUpdateInterval](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html#setMinimumLogicUpdateInterval%28int%29) methods.

On projects that I've worked on, including one in Slick, I find that anything in the 30-60 logic updates per second (30.3 milliseconds to 16.6 milliseconds between updates) works great, and gives you the smoothness you need from your movement, physics, and collision calculations.

Literally what that means is, for a 30-60 logic updates per second range, you want to do the following:

```
container.setMinimumLogicUpdateInterval(16);  // max 60 logic updates per second
container.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(31);  // min 30 logic updates per second
```

Also, it's a common mistake to try to calculate the `timeRemaing` value, but you don't want to do this. You simply want to multiply how much you move, by how much time has passed. If 30 milliseconds have passed, that's about 1/33rd of a second, so you should move your game object by 1/33rd of the amount it would move in 1 second.

```
float timeElapsed = delta/1000f;

playerVelocity.y += (GRAVITY * timeElapsed);
```

With the upper/lower bounds set as specified above, you're sure that `timeElapsed` will always be a value between `0.03` and `0.06`. If your game gets bogged down and your frame rate slows down, your logic updates still won't go outside these bounds. What will happen instead is the whole game will appear to slow down (as it should, just like on the old Sega days when there was too much on the screen), but collisions and physics calculations will still work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it's reassuring to see that there isn't some magical solution that I couldn't figure out. Why would you consider the timeRemaining approach a mistake? I had originally had my velocity multiplied by the time elapsed, but it meant that the collision code needed a big rewrite, as the player could travel more than a whole tile in one tick and thus 'skip' tiles.

Comment: Yeah, I may have overstated it, but I guess where I've seen the `timeRemaining` go awry is when people try to use that value to figure out how much more time they have to do other things, like AI calculations, etc. It's not that you can't use it, it's just that with the various ways to approach this problem, hooking everything into the `delta` value will give you the most reliable results.

Comment: As for players moving too fast for collision, there are a couple of ways to approach that issue. One would be to do the collision calculation over the entire space that the player had traversed (if they player moved 3 tiles, then you need to figure out of the collision happened with any of them, and bounce them back. The other, much simpler way is to either increase the granularity of your logic updates (adjusting your min/max logic update intervals), or make the player move more slowly.

Comment: One final way I might approach that is, to cast the collision boundary forward (rather than backward) and if they player *might* collide with something in close proximity, then you'll need to do more fine grained collision detection between the player and *just those items that are close by* over the next couple of frames. Obviously if you're doing a game similar to Sonic the Hedgehog, then you're dealing with very fast movement, and that movement is central to the gameplay, so you can't really cheat with that.

Comment: I'll bet that **part** of the reason that Sonic (and all his friends) navigate the world in a collision circle is because calculations of collisions between circles and other objects (especially other circles) are mathematically simpler (and therefore faster) than complex collisions between multi-sided polygons.